# What is the point of being able to exercise Dissenter or Appraisal Rights in a publicly traded company?

Tags: stocks, corporation, interactive-brokers, corporate-governance

In the Interactive Brokers list of fees for [Corporate Actions & Dividend Processing](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=14718), there is a "$100 + external costs" fee for "requests to exercise Dissenter or Appraisal Rights". Under what conditions would I want to request to exercise Dissenter or Appraisal rights? If I disagreed with what a publicly traded corporation is planning to do, can't I simply sell my shares on the stock market, instead of paying $100+ to exercise my dissenter and appraisal rights?

Comment: If you owned a lot of shares of the company, REALLY a lot of shares, then it might be worth it to vote through IB and pay $100.  Otherwise, you could just sell the shares, exactly as you described in your question.